# PHP GDAL/OGR library usage, which approach is cleaner?

Tags: php, gdal, ogr

I will be using gdal/ogr for a new project. I want a lean but fully functional app, so will not be using other implementations such as mapserver, because they have extraneous components that I doubt will be needed in the application, even in the future. For the record, it is a GIS, but I am asking here on SO because there as so few examples of a GIS in php that uses  [GDAL/OGR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55543/using-gdal-ogr-exes-in-php)

**I basically have three options in mind:**

- use php's exec() function to run command line conversion utilities
- Use swig to generate a .dll and load it as an extension on php
- Use the php wrapper written by geonfr @https://github.com/geonef/php5-gdal/wiki

Which do you think is the most effective way to implement the library?

Comment: I would advice you to use php5-gdal. Why doing there work again?

Comment: Yes I thought that would probably be the best option, but its not recommended in a production environment and its considered unstable.....

Comment: A custom solution will need the same alpha, beta, unstable, stable staging. And I expect you starting at alpha state (like everyone))

Comment: yeah, you are right.... looking through the source it seems extensible if there are other functions I want to implement...

Comment: Ok. You should consider to answer this question by yourself after finishing tests. Would be interesting to hear about your results.

Comment: will do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Hmm, I have to wonder about this: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/php and http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/include

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wound up using the exec functions,  mostly because there was no time to get into swig or php extension development, which were the preferred methods for me, personally.
// here is a small sample snippet of it's usage, hopefully it will come in handy for someone else

```
public function convertToNewFormat($format)
        {
                return(
                    exec('ogr2ogr -f '
                        .$format
                        .' '.self::setNewFileLocation()
                        .' '.self::setOldFileLocation()));

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Symfony Process-Component, avoiding plain exec commands.
It has a great syntax and is very easy to use.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

```
$process = new Process('ls -lsa');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```