# Using ogr2ogr in a web page

Tags: html, gdal, ogr2ogr

Is it possible to use ogr2ogr to merge shapefiles within a html page ?

I would like to make a website page that allows me to search a computers directory to select two shapefiles then use ogr2ogr to merge the shapefiles and return that merged shapfile running GDAL like the below:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" merged.shp a.shp
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -append -update merged.shp b.shp
```

Any advise on where I need to look would be great.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and at what point that you get stuck. Without such info, no one can help you.

Comment: You can use the vsi* interfaces to read remote files (including zipped) directly into memory: https://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678797/php-gdal-ogr-library-usage-which-approach-is-cleaner